# Bonding on centos

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, bonding

I have host that running `OpenStack`. For public access, there bonding (mode active/passive) on nic1 and nic2. Right now both connect at the same switch.

Is it possible to connect different switch and make bonding redundancy?

Comment: You have 2 physical nic which you want to bind and the connect them to different switch?

Comment: Yes, that correct. Those switch using different pdu/power source.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have setup the bond in Active-Backup (bond mode 1) on the system you need only to move the nic2 cable to the other switch port.
When the current active Ethernet port going down (ex. nic1) the system will automatically use the nic2.
You can always check the bond current active inteface with:

```
cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
```